# what does [::-1] mean in python - slicing?

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I have a variable `a=range(0,5)` and i need to know **why** and **how** `a[::-1]` this works.   The answer i am getting is `range(4,-1,-1)`. Thanks for help.

P.S. *It is quite a basic question but as this question is answered in a very structured way, i tried to edit the question and make it more general and useful.*

Comment: It will give you a new list `b` where the elements are in reverse order of `a`. 
If `a=[0,1,2,3,4]`, `b=[4,3,2,1,0]`

Comment: regardless of what `a` is, `[::-1]` reverses its order.

Comment: It goes from end to start in steps of one, i.e. reverses the list.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis no, only if `__getitem__` works like the one from lists.

Comment: @timgeb I meant regardless of which list; the fact that it is `range(0,5)` does not make any difference. But the order gets reversed for strings and tuples as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Slicing**

1. Negative numbers for `start` and `stop` mean "from the end". It's essianlly equivalent of `len-value`.
2. Negative number for `step` means "in reverse order".
3. Empty start means 0 i.e. 1st element.
4. Empty stop means `len`. Stop parameter is exclusive!

So `[::-1]` means from 1st element to last element in steps of 1 in reverse order.

5. If you have `[start:stop]` it's the same as `step=1`. So `[:-1]` it means all but last. again it's the last element *exclusive*. It's the same as `[:-1:]` or `[0:-1:1]`.

If you have only `start`, it returns one element given by the index `start`. Thus `[-1]` means last element. Same as `[len-1]` would.

**range**

Range also has syntax `start,stop,step` but the step has a different meaning. Step is added repeatedly starting from `start`. So you start at `4`, and go down by adding `-1` until you hit `stop`, also exclusively. So `range(5,0)[::-1]` is equivalent to `range(4,-1,-1)`. You can compute it.

**Why interpreter says `range(0,5)[::-1] => range(4, -1, -1)`?**

Python interpreter is smart enough to convert a slice of `range` into another `range`. This is an optimization, ranges are generators. They are dynamic, i.e. they don't hold all the elements in the memory at once. It the interpreter you are using worked step-by-step, it would have to generate whole list, just to be able to iterate in a reverse order. It's smarter to compute new generator.

How it is done, is explained in detail Łukasz'es answer.

Btw. you can force it to generate a `list`, and prevent from optimizing:

```
   range(0,5)[::-1]
=> range(4, -1, -1)
   list(range(0,5))[::-1]
=> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Yea I was already editing it. I made a mistake. You are obviously right.

Comment: according to this 'b' should be range(5,0,-1). i.e. it should start from 5 and ends at 0. how this (4,-1,-1) came ?

Answer (score 5):

The method you used is called `Slicing` in Python.

**Slicing syntax** in python is as follows,

`[ <first element to include> : <first element to exclude> : <step> ]`

where adding the `step` part is optional.

---

Here is a representation of how python list considers positive and negative index.

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
   0   1   2   3   4   5 
  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

---

When using,

```
a = range(10)
# a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

a[10:0:-1] #or
a[-1:-10:-1]
# Output = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Why because, when we give `0`/`-10` as the second parameter, it excludes the element in the `0`/`-10`th position.

So easy way is to omit the second parameter in slicing. That is,

```
a[10::-1] #or
a[-1::-1]
# Output = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
# Which is what we want.
```

In order to further simplify, if you omit both start and end value and just give step as -1, it again yields the same result.

```
a[::-1]
# Output = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
# The -1 at step position traverse the element from the last to the beginning
```

---

Here is a simple cheat sheet for understanding Slicing,

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
a[:]         # a copy of the whole array

a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step

a[-1]    # last item in the array
a[-2:]   # last two items in the array
a[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
```

---

To understand more about slicing, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

---

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

[`compute_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Objects/rangeobject.c#L322) function is used to convert between existing `range` object (`rangeobject *r`) and it's new value. As you can see, it's done as O(1) operation based on start/stop/step values of both `range` and passed `slice`.

```cpp
static PyObject *
compute_slice(rangeobject *r, PyObject *_slice)
{
    PySliceObject *slice = (PySliceObject *) _slice;
    rangeobject *result;
    PyObject *start = NULL, *stop = NULL, *step = NULL;
    PyObject *substart = NULL, *substop = NULL, *substep = NULL;
    int error;

    error = _PySlice_GetLongIndices(slice, r->length, &start, &stop, &step);
    if (error == -1)
        return NULL;

    substep = PyNumber_Multiply(r->step, step);
    if (substep == NULL) goto fail;
    Py_CLEAR(step);

    substart = compute_item(r, start);
    if (substart == NULL) goto fail;
    Py_CLEAR(start);

    substop = compute_item(r, stop);
    if (substop == NULL) goto fail;
    Py_CLEAR(stop);

    result = make_range_object(Py_TYPE(r), substart, substop, substep);
    if (result != NULL) {
        return (PyObject *) result;
    }
fail:
    Py_XDECREF(start);
    Py_XDECREF(stop);
    Py_XDECREF(step);
    Py_XDECREF(substart);
    Py_XDECREF(substop);
    Py_XDECREF(substep);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Nice stuff, I though OP's asking how is it equivalent, but I guess the real confusion comes from the cleverness of interpreter and transformation of generator by slicing.