# how to i get os.listdir with follow the file?

Tags: python, list, python-os

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlT4I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHEZE.png)

Hello, I have encountered a problem. When I use os.listdir, I hope that the effect of picture 1 will appear, but the effect of python is reversed.
I would like to ask how can I get the data and want the effect of picture 1

Comment: Do not post images of text. Post them as text (plain or formatted).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-alphanumeric list order from os.listdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
files = os.listdir()[::-1]
print(files)
```

`somelist[::-1]` reverses the list
starts from the end towards the first taking each element as step=-1

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134109/18359159)

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list of directories in an arbitrary order. This might work for OP on their current environment but can easily break for other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Do not post images of text (your second image). Use `reverse()`

```py
files = os.listdir()
files.reverse()
```

It is unclear how the files are ordered in the screenshot given. This solution may not work in all environments, though this will solve the symptom of your problem as given.